# How do you access Target in a Beam ParticleSystem in UDK?

Tags: udk

I have a Beam ParticleSystem which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of ParticleSystem]

I want to set the Target location when the effect plays, but I can't figure out how to do that from UnrealScript.

I've looked at the UDN page on it: [link](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/ParticleSystemReference.html#Beam%20_TypeData)

But this doesn't seem to explain how to access the relevant info from script. I am currently able to get the effect to play, but I just can't set the endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be quite simple:

```
function PlayTeleportBeamSystem(Actor SourceActor, ParticleSystem PSystem, Vector Target, optional Vector Source = Vect(0, 0, 0))
{
    local ParticleSystemComponent PSysComponent;

    PSysComponent = new(SourceActor) class'ParticleSystemComponent';
    PSysComponent.SetTemplate(PSystem);
    SourceActor.AttachComponent(PSysComponent);
    PSysComponent.ActivateSystem();
    if(!IsZero(Source))
    {
        PSysComponent.SetBeamSourcePoint(0, Source, 0);
        PSysComponent.SetBeamSourcePoint(1, Source, 1);
    }
    PSysComponent.SetBeamEndPoint(0, Target);
    PSysComponent.SetBeamEndPoint(1, Target);

    m_TargetedTeleportSystemComponentArray.AddItem(PSysComponent);
}
```